# Date format used for json

Tags: java, json, http, server, response

I found a date format looks like      **'creationDate:1509966414000'**     for an application for saving the creation date of an object in HTTP response. I am unable to parse this date format to real date, So guys could anyone help me to find out the architecture for creating this type of date format?

Comment: It's just a millisecond timestamp. Translates to 2017-11-06T11:06:54Z.

Comment: search about unix timestamp

Comment: if you are already using some json parser, you could create a custom datetimeAdapter and link it to the json parser

Comment: There's also a good possibility your JSON library supports that format out of the box, or with a configuration tweak.

Comment: Thanks to all, now I understand the procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `Date(long date)`.

```
public class MilliSecondToDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long milliSecond = 1509966414000L;
        Date date = new Date(milliSecond);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks xxy for helping me to find out the format. Actually I was thinking that it's a new kind of timestamp. Thanks again sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can Try Calendar or Date instance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Long timeInMilis = 1509966414000l;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(timeInMilis);
        System.out.println("Using Calendar instance : "+cal.getTime());

        Date date = new Date(timeInMilis);
        System.out.println("Using date instance : "+date);

    }
```

O/P :

```
Using Calendar instance : Mon Nov 06 16:36:54 IST 2017
Using date instance : Mon Nov 06 16:36:54 IST 2017
```

Comment: welcome  @PawanDwivedee, you can upvote my work that will inspire me :).